# How to start docker containers and keep them alive during script execution on MacOS

Tags: bash, docker, macos, shell

I have a shell script that tries to start two docker containers in a for loop. The script should not continue the rest of its execution before it has detected the output "Service will run on port" in stdout.

The following code works fine on linux:

```
for i in "${functionsToStart[@]}"
 do
   echo "Starting ${i}"
   (bash start-server.sh) | grep -q "Service will run on port"
 done

#more commands
.
.
.
```

In MacOs however this will start docker in a virtual environment (docker desktop), and the grep will never match.

When I try to run this as a sub process:

```
(bash start-server.sh &) | grep -q "Service will run on port"
```

The grep matches fine but it also kills my sub process and therefore also the container.

I need the containers to keep running for the rest of the script execution, how do I do this in MacOs?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling with this issue for MacOs.

The start-server.sh script mentioned above is the script that starts my docker container. The answer here was using the correct options when executing the docker run command from within the script:

docker run ***-itd***